# Sending POST request in ESB mule

Tags: java, groovy, mule, esb

I try to send the post request to API using ESB mule. Hence i have created flow like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:json="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json" xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
    xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json/current/mule-json.xsd">
    <http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" host="0.0.0.0" port="8110" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration"/>
    <http:request-config name="HTTP_Request_Configuration" protocol="HTTPS" host="api.bonanza.com" port="443" doc:name="HTTP Request Configuration"/>
    <flow name="bonanza_fetchtoken_ceFlow">
        <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/fetchtoken" allowedMethods="GET" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <message-properties-transformer doc:name="Message Properties">
            <add-message-property key="X-BONANZLE-API-DEV-NAME" value="t*****I"/>
            <add-message-property key="X-BONANZLE-API-CERT-NAME" value="l*****F"/>
        </message-properties-transformer>
        <set-payload value="fetchTokenRequest" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
        <set-property propertyName="Content-Type" value="application/json" doc:name="Property"/>
        <json:object-to-json-transformer doc:name="Object to JSON"/>
        <http:request config-ref="HTTP_Request_Configuration" path="/api_requests/secure_request" method="POST" doc:name="HTTP">
            <http:success-status-code-validator values="0..599"/>
        </http:request>
    </flow>
</mule>
```

In the API documentation, they have provided the sample code for java to send and receive response and it is working in my local too. The java code snippet is  below.

```
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;

public class FetchToken {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            String devId = "t******I";
            String certId = "l*******F";

            URL url = new URL("https://api.bonanza.com/api_requests/secure_request");
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
            connection.setRequestProperty("X-BONANZLE-API-DEV-NAME", devId);
            connection.setRequestProperty("X-BONANZLE-API-CERT-NAME", certId);

            OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());

            String requestName = "fetchTokenRequest";

            writer.write(requestName);
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();

            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
            String response = in.readLine();

            JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);

            if (jsonResponse.optString("ack").equals("Success") 
                    && jsonResponse.optJSONObject("fetchTokenResponse") != null) {
                // Success! Now read more keys from the json object
                JSONObject fetchTokenJson = jsonResponse.optJSONObject("fetchTokenResponse");

                System.out.println("Your token: " + fetchTokenJson.optString("authToken"));
                System.out.println("Token expiration time: " + fetchTokenJson.optString("hardExpirationTime"));
                System.out.println("Authentication URL: " + fetchTokenJson.optString("authenticationURL"));
            }


        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

I am not java expertise. How they are sending post payload (fetchTokenRequest) in Java in the above sample. How can i send same payload in the mule ESB.

If it is stream post payload, how can i send stream post payload in ESB mule ?

Comment: Hi @Simbu, there is a set-payload found in palette of mule anypoint studio. Use that to set the payload as  "fetchTokenRequest".

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have tried set payload as like below but it throws me an API error. `<set-payload value="fetchTokenRequest" doc:name="Set Payload"/>`

Answer (score 1):

In your sample, whatever payload your http listener is listening to will be your payload for post request. To use a different payload, use `<set-payload doc:name="Set Payload" value="your_value"/>` before outbound http.

Set `Content-Type` to `application/json`
After `set-payload`, use `<json:object-to-json-transformer/>`

Comment: I have tried set payload. `<set-payload value="fetchTokenRequest" doc:name="Set Payload"/>` it throws me an API error. 

Between I have tried to hit request from postman tool. That will also throws same error as like mule esb. In postman, i have set up like in body as 'raw' and set the payload inside as 'fetchTokenRequest'. 

Dont know how can i send payload as like in above java program.

Comment: I have used like `<set-property propertyName="Content-Type" value="text/plain" doc:name="Property"/>` . Edited my original flow as well.

Comment: It is API related error.
`{
  "ack": "Failure",
  "version": "1.0beta",
  "timestamp": "2016-03-09T09:53:50.000Z",
  "errorMessage": {
    "message": "Cannot determine what type of request you are making. Often this can be the result of data that has not been escaped before being passed to the API. If you are passing data with quotation marks or other special characters, you should translate it to JSON, then escape it, before sending it over the API."
  }
}`

Comment: See my update, the external service expects `application/json` not text `Content_type`

Comment: Yes. I have tried it same API error. Updated my esb mule flow config in post. More over i have placed complete java program in the original post. This java program returning token for me.

Comment: Itv looks like you're setting https credentials wrong... Payload is setup correctly. I'd open up a new question for https thing

Comment: Where i have to set `X-BONANZLE-API-DEV-NAME` and cert name in mule ?

Comment: I could not see any change in my error. Then how can i close this question.

Between i have changed the property as like below too. No change in the error.

`<set-property propertyName="Content-Type" value="application/json" doc:name="Property"/>
        <set-property propertyName="X-BONANZLE-API-DEV-NAME" value="t*******I" doc:name="Property"/>
        <set-property propertyName="X-BONANZLE-API-CERT-NAME" value="l*****F" doc:name="Property"/>`